# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, import

I'm new to javascript but for some reason I have this Error
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/paddle net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
my code looks like this
**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title >Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
        #gameScreen {
            border: 1px solid black;
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import Paddle from "/src/paddle";


let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 800;


let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

paddle.draw(ctx);
```

**paddle.js**

```
export default class Paddle {
   constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
       this.width = 150;
       this.height = 30;

       this.position = {
           x: gameWidth / 2 - this.width / 2,
           y: gameHeight - this.height - 10
       };
   }
   draw(ctx) {
       ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
   
   }

}
```

I get the error in first line of index.js I appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 17):

this how I solved this problem instead of

```
import Paddle from "/src/paddle";
```

just type 'js' as extinction

```
import Paddle from "/src/paddle.js";
```

Comment: also you can use "./className.js"