# Import/Export in Javascript, I get a "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic project and I am trying to use ES6 Modules to split my code into multiple files. So I wanted to test it first using some basic stuff like exporting a single const. But it's not working and it's throwing me the "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)".

The second file code(the file that I want to export the code from):

```
export const myName = 'Name';
```

The first file code:

```
import { myName } from "./appTwo";

console.log(myName);
```

I looked it up online and most of the answers are regarding backend. I did make my script tag type="module", it still doesn't work.

Comment: The path is wrong

Comment: holy this is embarassing, guess I should take a break. Thank you very much tho!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [net::ERR\_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898579/neterr-aborted-404-not-found-javascript)