# Resolving NET::ERR_ABORTED 404 Error in JavaScript Import/Export

Tags: javascript

I have a very `javascript` project

There are two `js` files in the project

[image]

> I have **exported** a **function** in **`template.js`**

[image]

> And in another file, which is my main file, which I **addressed** in
> the `html`, I `import` that function and use it.

[image]

> Now the project execution time gives this error
>
> GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/template net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[image]

I hope I explained my problem well

I found a similar error at this address

> [Import/Export in Javascript, I get a "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828788/import-export-in-javascript-i-get-a-neterr-aborted-404-not-found)

But there was no detailed explanation about the problem and how to fix the problem
I tried to explain my problem in detail

Thank you very much for helping me with this error

Comment: 404 means the file doesn't exist. It's because the file is called `template.js` and not `template`. You forgot the file extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [net::ERR\_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898579/neterr-aborted-404-not-found-javascript)

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you very much, it was done. Thank you very much
But I had seen that they do not add an extension
For example, in Angular, they do not put the extension of ts or js files
Shouldn't it work here too?

Comment: That's different, there you'd have a module bundler which resolves the dependencies differently. This is raw ES modules

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Regarding the repetitiveness of the question
I searched a lot for this answer but couldn't find anything
Maybe the title of this question can help some others
Because I think my explanation was good
But if there is a problem, I will delete this

Comment: Just click "yes" above where it asked whether the other question solved it